# OCaml shebang syntax error

Tags: ocaml, syntax-error, shebang

```
$ cat hello.ml 
#!/usr/bin/env ocamlrun ocaml

let rec main = print_string "Hello World!\n"

$ ./hello.ml 
Hello World!

$ ocaml hello.ml 
Hello World!

$ ocamlc -o hello hello.ml 
File "hello.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Syntax error

$ ocamlopt -o hello hello.ml 
File "hello.ml", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Syntax error
```

Similar to Erlang, OCaml permits shebangs in scripted mode, but borks in compiled mode. Is there a more idiomatic shebang in OCaml, one that doesn't trigger a syntax error during compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sed` as a preprocessor. To remove the shebang on the first line, if found, pass:

```
-pp 'sed "1 s/^#\!.*$//"'
```

to `ocamlc` or `ocamlopt`.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't want to require OCaml users to use special compilation flags just to handle shebang lines, but I'm glad you got this to work.

Comment: It would be cool if the compilers automatically stripped the shebang. Maybe a request for enhancement.

Comment: Could you ask them? You're more in the know, so they'll more likely listen to you.

Comment: ocamlc -pp "tail +2"

Answer (score 3):

There is not a directive that I know of which works with both the toplevel and the OCaml compilers, but you can use ocamlscript as an in-between option.

http://martin.jambon.free.fr/ocamlscript.html

ocamlscript uses ocamlfind + ocamlopt in the background to (re-)compile your code when it is executed.  With ocamlscript installed, you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ocamlscript
```

It does not give you direct toplevel compatibility, but it allows you to avoid a separate compilation step with many programs.  The web site has decent documentation and examples.

Comment: Bah, ocamlscript fails to compile in Mac OS X. Error: could not find `ocamlfind`.

Comment: Do you have ocamlfind installed? It is required by ocamlscript.

Comment: Please be sure you have ocamlfind, which is very standard for OCaml and you should always have. I use ocamlscript on Mac all the time without problems.

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally, ocamlfind fails to install on Mac OS X, so I'll contact the author about that.

Comment: I've never had a problem *compiling* `ocamlfind` on OS X. You might want to try the `./configure && make && sudo make install` route.

Comment: The ocamlfind repository doesn't build with `./configure && make && sudo make install`, because the docs must be built first. I switched from the repository to a tarball and everything worked.